# Sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{8}{n^2+9n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a problem with this sum, I've been trying to solve it for a while now without success.

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{8}{n^2+9n}\right)$$

I tried this which I found in my texbook which seems relative, but Im not sure how to apply it to the problem:
$$a_n=f(n)-f(n+k) \  ,\forall n\geq1$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{8}{n^2+9n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n^2+9n+8}{n^2+9n}\right)=\ln\left({n^2+9n+8}\right)-\ln\left({n^2+9n}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n =\ln \left(1+\dfrac8{n^2+9n}\right) = \ln \left(\dfrac{n^2+9n+8}{n^2+9n}\right) = \ln (n+1) - \ln(n) + \ln(n+8) - \ln(n+9)$$
Hence,
$$a_n = b_{n+1} - b_n$$
where
$$b_n = \ln(n) - \ln(n+8)$$

Answer (score 2):

Finally,

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\ln \left( {1 + \frac{8}{{{n^2} + 9n}}} \right)}   \\
&=& \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\ln \frac{{n + 1}}{n}}  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\ln \frac{{n + 8}}{{n + 9}}}  \\
&=& \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}}  - \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n + 8}}{{n + 9}}}  \\
&=& \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^8 {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}}  + \ln \prod\limits_{n = 9}^\infty  {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}}  - \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n + 8}}{{n + 9}}}   \\
&=& \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^8 {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}}  + \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n + 9}}{{n + 8}}}  - \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n + 8}}{{n + 9}}}   \\
&=& \ln \prod\limits_{n = 1}^8 {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}}  \\
&=& 2\ln 3 
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large S}&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{1 + {8 \over n^2+9n}}
=8\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over n^{2} + 9n + 8x}
=8\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + 9n + 8x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> The sum over $\ds{n}$ can be performed by *" standard means "*. Upon integration the result is
>   $\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\color{#66f}{\large 2\ln\pars{3} \approx 2.1972}\\ \hline\end{array}$.